# Firebase Android resource generation error in Firebase Unity SDK due to Python 2.7 being removed in macOS 12.3 Monterey

Tags: python, c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am getting this error while opening unity with firebase sdk 8.7.0.

```
Unable to find command line tool python required for Firebase Android resource generation.
python is required to generate the Firebase Android resource file google-services.xml from Assets/Firebase/GoogleService-Info.plist. Without Firebase Android resources, your app will fail to initialize.
python was distributed with each Firebase Unity SDK plugin, was it deleted?

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): ApplicationName='python', CommandLine='"/Users/xxx/Documents/unity-project/Assets/Firebase/Editor/generate_xml_from_google_services_json.py" -i "Assets/Firebase/GoogleService-Info.plist" -l --plist', CurrentDirectory='/Users/xxx/Documents/unity-project', Native error= mono-io-layer-error (2)
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x002dc] in <0463b2ef957545c0a51b42f372cd4fbb>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x0003a] in <0463b2ef957545c0a51b42f372cd4fbb>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
  at GooglePlayServices.CommandLine.RunViaShell (System.String toolPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] envVars, GooglePlayServices.CommandLine+IOHandler ioHandler, System.Boolean useShellExecution, System.Boolean stdoutRedirectionInShellMode) [0x002dc] in Z:\tmp\tmp.cvthQg1D2s\third_party\unity\unity_jar_resolver\source\AndroidResolver\src\CommandLine.cs:631 
  at GooglePlayServices.CommandLine.Run (System.String toolPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] envVars, GooglePlayServices.CommandLine+IOHandler ioHandler) [0x00000] in Z:\tmp\tmp.cvthQg1D2s\third_party\unity\unity_jar_resolver\source\AndroidResolver\src\CommandLine.cs:510 
  at Firebase.Editor.PythonExecutor.Run (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] envVars, GooglePlayServices.CommandLine+IOHandler ioHandler) [0x00000] in Z:\tmp\tmp.dYyxJerQE9\firebase\app\client\unity\editor\src\PythonExecutor.cs:180 
  at Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson.RunResourceGenerator (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] arguments, System.String inputPath, System.Boolean showCommandLine) [0x0001b] in Z:\tmp\tmp.dYyxJerQE9\firebase\app\client\unity\editor\src\GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson.cs:521 
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
 #4  (Mono JIT Code) [Z:\tmp\tmp.dYyxJerQE9\firebase\app\client\unity\editor\src\GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson.cs:407] Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:ReadBundleIds (string)
```

I tried running python `/Users/xxx/Documents/unity-project/Assets/Firebase/Editor/generate_xml_from_google_services_json.py" -i "Assets/Firebase/GoogleService-Info.plist" -l --plist` in shell and it successfully output my app's bundle id `com.myapp.bundle`

I also tried reimporting firebase sdk, restart unity, restart mac, but none of them solves the issue.

I searched similar issues but unfortunately found no solution.

What I did before this error showed up I upgraded macOS to the latest Monterey 12.3 I know it's because Python 2.7 was erased, but I don't know how to fix it.

I would appreciate some help. Getting pretty desperate, I've been on this all day long.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-unity-sdk/issues/154
https://github.com/techyworm10/firebase-unity-sdk-editor-python-fix
these link help you
i have exact error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).